# SQLGetDiagRec and MSDN

Tags: c++, odbc, msdn

On [the MSDN-page for `SQLGetDiagRec()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I see following:

> SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO: The *MessageText buffer was too small to hold the requested diagnostic message. No diagnostic records were generated. To determine that a truncation occurred, the application must compare BufferLength to the actual number of bytes available, which is written to *StringLengthPtr.

The problem is that that's the one and only mention of `StringLengthPtr`.

What's the right one, and how do we get the docs fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, taking a look at the description of the individual arguments, the only one which fits the bill is `TextLengthPtr`. Which actually has is a very similar name.

I submitted a suggestion to correct that, we'll see when (and whether) they get around to it.